# Ruby RSA public_encrypt facing Given final block not properly padded error in Java

Tags: java, ruby, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am implementing Symmetric key encryption with another entity (let's call it APIProvider). Whenever I send them a request, they respond with an error -

```
Given final block not properly padded#012#011at
```

Here is the code that I have implemented

Step 1: I extract the public key from the Certificate

```
def extract_public_key_from_certificate
  certificate_file_content = File.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/certificates/GSTN_G2B_SANDBOX_UAT_public.cer")
  cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(certificate_file_content)    
  cert.public_key
end
```

Step 2: I generate my own AES-256 key

Step 3: I encrypt the key using public key and send it using HTTParty

```
@encrypted_key = Base64.encode64(@public_key.public_encrypt(@app_key))
```

The APIProvider responds with an error -

```
Given final block not properly padded#012#011at
```

**Other details for debugging**

The AES Key that I generate looks like this

```
3aeMkWqxAQeQBp7LKl49FCBDYcwtl9QK6dDdeD7fzM8=
```

The Public Key that I extracted from the certificate

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn4ccEVpmsRfrUvxK6yfk g6brTJoGe90qzDNWOSqXJh51mwyLKjd7mccSaL7oMKTkXKLRmZvZtR1NYWnAU6nu KNjDQOC6LTzhoSE7siL2rneh0+A9rXyjEl6FuYp+ilV5rrsuWR3RLCUDYOFkIobH Ddhbl/B8Ol05bLrZvU1XIn7E98j47q/rWGp+SiHA5Ui7hAw+b2UCv8os8HWKmr6z NDziKPCGabrZTws/e1XJ0/uW5mxTfX/DOjbukP+aosMrlD1kVocJr+SrVRKzIOiC 7FYuY6q2CGY5+soXz8cQi7be6h5wJvZB9HdU6mYzTk4yw/bnNvuqlGIgoGF0nZzn MwIDAQAB -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My encrypted key looks like this

```
evpqDyverZMmJVWhoZXNrAnpveNKDuQfiKt5nPJgTTtUMAeUp3IT7F+8cAad gCowubOwesJ7/hsMeAkVbLHMi1YUsWZ1xsDjTXUihOiRYLId8/Blyf5nP+wt AeG5MBfIWgP0o7cotve4lmH8/4Gh8Nh36ZH1jYEewwtjiNXE6lPtY3CESHIe lgPSf+vGy+O1YLKpDGPNu0twoBJfjeL9COnjJkpzOHofoh28SBMJoDeFrOGw cbkHC8fGLgv+sAkKdhy342aHBNeBlmLDt3McI2u+oHPniwtUyHFpJJ40bW2k IZeSpCT79ZNolXU3dcbXAwiJkcmdWEBGD40irAQaTw==
```

1. APIProvider has confirmed they are using PKCS1 padding. It's the same that I am using. [Infact I have checked that PKCS1 padding is the default in public_encrypt](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html#method-i-public_encrypt)
2. The error message looks like it's part of their AES encryption-decryption. Here we are using RSA. It could be a standard message whenever they are not able to decrypt the message.
3. Their application is working. In fact if I use a key generated using Java code (as implemented by others), it works. I am probably the only one implementing it in Ruby.

What am I missing here?

Edit 1 -

**Here is the Java code that works**

```
    public class EncryptionUtil {

    //public key url or location on the desktop for testing
    public static String publicKeyUrl1 ="/Users/vikrambahl/Work/gstn-keys/GSTN_G2B_SANDBOX_UAT_public.cer";
            private static String file;

    private static PublicKey readPublicKey(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
        CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
        PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
        return pk;

    }


    public static String encrypt(byte[] plaintext) throws Exception,NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {

        PublicKey key = readPublicKey(publicKeyUrl1);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedByte= cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
        String encodedString = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedByte));
        return encodedString;
    }

    public static String generateEncAppkey(byte[] key){
        try {
            return encrypt(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }       
}

private static void produceSampleData(){
    try {
        //Generation of app key. this will be in encoded.
        String appkey = generateSecureKey();
        System.out.println("App key in encoded : "+ appkey);
        //Encrypt with GSTN public key
        String encryptedAppkey = EncryptionUtil.generateEncAppkey(decodeBase64StringTOByte(appkey));
        System.out.println("Encrypted App Key ->"+ encryptedAppkey);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Pre 1.9.3 Ruby Padding**

Also It seems that the PKCS1 encryption in pre 1.9.3 Ruby was different than what it is currently. [Here is the commit where the change was brought in.](https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4421) However it is more to do with how the public key was generated (PUBLIC KEY BEGINS VS PUBLIC RSA KEY BEGINS). Nonetheless I have tried to recreate the public key using the old standard and then encrypting my symmetric key.

That didn't work either. Here is the code for that

```
def convert_public_key_to_old_ruby_pkcs1_format

  gst_pem_file = File.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/certificates/GSTN_G2B_SANDBOX_UAT_public.pem")

  rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(gst_pem_file)
  modulus = rsa.n
  exponent = rsa.e

  ary = [OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer.new(modulus), OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer.new(exponent)]
  pub_key = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence.new(ary)
  base64 = Base64.encode64(pub_key.to_der)

  #This is the equivalent to the PKCS#1 encoding used before 1.9.3
  pem = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n#{base64}-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
  the_public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem)
end
```

Edit/Update - 2

**Rails 3 / Ruby 1.9.1 did not work either**
I created a rails 3, ruby 1.9.1 app and tested. That didn't work either. I am yet to assess what was the exact change and whether the current version of padding that we use is PKCS1ver 1 or PKCS1 ver1.5. The investigation continues.

**Let's try and use some symmetric encryption gems instead**
I did read through the code of a gem that offered symmetric encryption. Let me go ahead and use a few of them to see if my implementation is incorrect.

Comment: "What am I missing here?"  The java code. It's not possible to answer your question without it.

Comment: Have added the Java code. If I generate a key in ruby and use Java code to encrypt my message, it works. Also added a hint about PKCS1 padding changes in Ruby OpenSSL, incase the answer lies somewhere in that direction.